# html vertical align the text inside input type button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button with height of '22px' , and that the text inside the button will be vertically aligned in the center of the button. I tried everything , and can't find out how to do it.

How can this be done?

**UPDATE:**
this is my code:

```css
.test1 label {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 31%;
  margin-right: -2px;
}

.test1 input {
  float: left;
  width: 69%;
  margin-right: -2px;
}

.testbutton {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  color: #606060;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font: bold 12px/100% Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <label for="test" title="test">test</label>
  <input style="width:18px; float:left;" type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" tabindex="5" />
  <input class="testbutton" id="testbutton" style="width:60px;" type="button" value="Import" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 96):

### Using flexbox:

```css
.testbutton {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<button>a button</button>
```

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) (check [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), depending on your needs).

Comment: The best solution I've seen so far. Also works well with varying height buttons. (For example, buttons with a border)

Comment: To also center it horizontally, add "justify-content: space-around;"

Comment: Getting back on my previous comment, this does not seem to be a proper solution because `button` element cannot have `display: flex;`. Check out this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flexbox-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements

Answer (score 61):

Try adding the property `line-height: 22px;` to the code.

Comment: I added "line-hight" property , and it's still not working.. I've updated my question with my code.. thank's!

Comment: Hi! You have tried you code and the text "import" inside the button is correctly align, I don't undestand what is worng. I have try this in Firefox and chrome.

Comment: I'm using IE so i didn't check it in Firefox or chrome, I changed the input to button instead and now it works.. thank's for your help!

Comment: experimenting with line-height seemed to work for me too, eventually...thanks!

Comment: Be careful using this. If your text ever needs to wrap, it will break the layout. I recommend peterhry's answer below. Switching to a button tag will automatically center the content vertically, and will wrap content nicely if needed.

Comment: This worked for me on a <button> but not on an <input>

Comment: I set `line-height: 0;` for all different size buttons to vertically align text, svg images, etc properly and automatically. The button adjusts its own size according to content.

Answer (score 16):

Use the `<button>` tag instead. `<button>` labels are vertically centered by default.

Comment: Yes, the content inside a button tag is centered by default in every browser. Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/peterhry/pen/arDAF

Comment: For the record, this was a useful hack before flexbox was widely supported but there is no good reason to use it today.

Comment: It looks centered in some cases, but its not in 50% position.

Answer (score 7):

I found that using a fixed width with padding seems to work (in ff at least)

```
.Btn
 {
   width:75px;
   padding:10px;
 }
```

Try it at:-

http://jsfiddle.net/stevenally/z32kg/

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar issue with my button. I included `line-height: 0;` and it appears to have worked. Also mentioned by @anddero.

```
button[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4056A1;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #4056A1;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 2px 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've given up trying to align my text on buttons! Now, if I need it, I'm using `<a>` tags, like so:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" style="display:block;font-size:1em;padding:5px;cursor:default;" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();">Submit</a>
```

So, if the document's font size is 12px, my "button" will have 22px height. And the text will be vertically align. That in theory, because, in some casses, an unequal padding of "6px 5px 4px 5px" will do the job done.

Although, is a hack, this technique is pretty good for solving compatibility issues in older browsers too, like IE6!

Answer (score 2):

If your button weren't floated, you could use `vertical-align:middle;` to center the text inside it. After lots of experimentation, this was the *only* solution I could find that worked in IE without changing markup. (in Chrome, button text seems to be automatically centered without this hack).

But you use a `float:left` which forces the element to be a block element (your `display:inline-block` is ignored), whcih in turn prevents vertical-align from working because vertical-align doesn't work inside a block element.

So you have three choices:

- stop using floats in this form, and use `inline` and `inline-block` elements to simulate floating.
- as @stefan notes above, use another element like an <a> and use javascript to submit the form.
- accept that in IE your buttons will be off by 1px vertically.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is use reset.css. It normalizes the default stylesheet across browsers, and coincidentally allows button { vertical-align: middle; } to work just fine. Give it a shot - I use it in virtually all of my projects just to kill little bugs like this.

https://gist.github.com/nathansmith/288292

Answer (score 0):

I had a button where the `background-image` had a shadow below it so the text alignment was off from the top. Changing the `line-height` wouldn't help. I added `padding-bottom` to it and it worked.

So what you have to do is determine the `line-height` you want to play with. So, for example, if I have a button who's height is truly `90px` but I want the line-height to be `80px` I would have something like this:

```
input[type=butotn].mybutton{
    background: url(my/image.png) no-repeat center top; /*Image is 90px x 150px*/
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px; /*shadow at the bottom is 10px (90px-10px)*/
    padding-bottom: 10px; /*the padding will make up for the lost height while maintaining the line-height to the proper height */

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It happens, no worries.