# How To Vertically Align Text On A Squarespace Button?

Tags: css, button, squarespace

I currently have one line of text it is perfectly centered, but when I add a second line of text it floats  beneath the first line.

I'd like it to be centered vertically even for multi-line button titles. How would I go about doing this using CSS?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to have fixed height? If not, remove the rule

```
.sqs-block-button-element.sqs-block-button-element--small {
    height: 16.4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get two elements of text on the same line?

If so, you would use `display: inline` in your css. This will make both lines appear inline or on the same line.

Comment: No I'm just trying to center the text vertically. Right now because the second line goes beneath the first line it's making the text off center (vertically).

Comment: Can you give me an example of the html/css code so i can get a clear understanding of what you need help with

Comment: Here's my website, it's in the middle of the front page that I'm having trouble with those buttons. http://www.bargainsight.com/

Comment: I think padding works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184856/html-vertical-align-the-text-inside-input-type-button